# Stream Reader to List, List to array and split the line valu , Make object of the split value and print it a random object in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, list, streamreader

Stream Reader to List, List to array and split the line valu , Make object of the split value and print it a random object in RichTextBox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following which is simpler :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Övning_3___Tipsmaskinen2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileLoader();
        }
        public class Bok
        {
            public string Titel;//Tittle
            public string Författare;//Author
            public string Boktyp;//TBookTYp
            public string ILager;// Bool or InSToridge 

            public Bok(string titel, string författare, string boktyp, string ilager) // method must have a return typ , funkar enbart om jag skriver in void
            {
                this.Titel = titel;
                this.Författare = författare;
                this.Boktyp = boktyp;
                this.ILager = ilager;
            }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "\t Titel : " + Titel + "\t Skribent : " + Författare + "  \t Boktyp: " + Boktyp + " \t Finns i lager : " + ILager;
            }
        }
        public List<Bok> FileLoader()
        {
            List<Bok> bokList = new List<Bok>();
            if (File.Exists("texter.txt"))
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("texter.txt", Encoding.Default, true);


                string item = "";
                while ((item = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] vektor = item.Split(new string[] { "###" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                    Bok k = new Bok(vektor[0], vektor[1], vektor[2], vektor[3]);
                    bokList.Add(k);
                }
                return bokList;
            }
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant call the File loader inside the button : FileLoader dose not exist in this current context                                                                                                          privat voidButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            FileLoader();
        }

Comment: There is an issue in the designer.cs file.  Double click on error which will go to line where error is occurring.  One of two things are wrong 1) The name of the button "Button1_Click" does not match exactly (uppercase/lowercase) with the name of the method in your code  2) The namespace in your code doesn't match the namespace in the designer.cs file : namespace Övning_3___Tipsmaskinen2